# LaTeX \bar in table

Tags: tables, math-mode, spacing

I'm very new to Latex. So i want to put a `\bar W` in a table but the bar is covered by the horizontal line of table.So it becomes invisible. I tried adding `\noalign{\smallskip}` after `\hline` but it cuts the vertical line of the table. Any suggestion?

Here is the code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l |  l |}
    \hline
    $\bar W $ & $A$  \\ \hline  \noalign{\smallskip}  
    $\bar W $ & $A$  \\ \hline 
    ... & ... \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

First bar is invisible and second one cuts the table.

Comment: Can you give an example of your code? Have you had a look at the latex wiki _[here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables)_?

Comment: You can use vertical struts in your table rows to move content up/down. For example, a vertical strut `\rule{0pt}{1em}` is high enough to expose the `\bar`. It's a zero-width rule of height `1em`. There are other ways as well, most of which are contained in [Column padding in tables](http://goo.gl/X3kPH).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `array` provides the length `\extrarowheight` that is added to each table row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{.5ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l |  l |}
    \hline
    $\bar W $ & $A$  \\ \hline
    $\bar W $ & $A$  \\ \hline
    ... & ... \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The effect can also be limited to the single table by setting `\extrarowheight` inside the `center` environment.